# Susy media query output & "screen"

Tags: susy-compass

Is there a particular reason that Susy doesn't use the common `@media screen and (min-width: 460px)` syntax for its media queries?

(or perhaps this is better asked as "why does almost everyone use `@media screen` or `@media only screen` for their media queries?")

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from mdn, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/Media_queries

> The only keyword prevents older browsers that do not support media
>   queries with media features from applying the given styles.

So if you use `only` keyword the old browsers that doesn't support media query will ignore that line at all. I guess most of the time we use polyfill for media query, for example `respond.js`, so it's a quite safe to ignore `only` keyword.

Comment: I knew that "only" was used to prevent older browsers from applying the styles. Given the recommended mobile-first strategy w/ Susy, it probably makes sense not to output "only" keywords. 

Still wondering why Susy doesn't output "screen" keyword, or if it can (or should) support it with a config option.